# Getting html data from CodeMirror, I get Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: codemirror

I get my html data from CodeMirror editor using getValue() that includes my jquery library and then the html data is loaded using the following code:

```
$("newIframe").contents().find("head").html(headDataTag[0]);
$("newIframe").contents().find("body").html(bodyDataTag[0]);
```

I checked the head and body of the document in the newIframe and the html data seems correct and render the html, javascript code correctly but not the jquery $(document).ready() code section.

Using Opera debugger and clicking on the network tab, it shows jquery downloaded (locally from a node server) correctly with a http status of 200 ok, however, it does not show under the source tab.

This same html data loads without problems using it in a main code without getting the data from CodeMirror editor.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If copy and paste the entire 10,618 lines of jquery code directly into my source html code, everything is working and I don't receive the $ is not defined error message.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the jQuery code just below:

```
$("newIframe").contents().find("head").html(headDataTag[0]);
$("newIframe").contents().find("body").html(bodyDataTag[0]);
```

To pure javascript code just below and everything started working:

```
var iframeId = document.getEelementById("newIframe");
var iframeDoc = iframeId.contentDocument || iframeId.contentWindow.document;

iframeDoc.open();
iframeDoc.write(editor.getValue) // CodeMirror data from it's editor window
iframeDoc.close();
```